# PHP is not working on ubuntu 14

Tags: server, apache2, php

I am trying to install php on my ubuntu machine. 1st I install apache2 on machine.... after that I install php7

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv
```

after that I restart my apache2 `service apache2 restart`

but still php is not working when I try to browse php page from localhost.

```
php -v
```

is also showing me output.... and telling me the php version.

in error log file of apche2 I got errors

```
restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu May 19 07:53:16.813504 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12487] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 19 07:53:16.813518 2016] [core:notice] [pid 12487] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu May 19 08:05:24.435502 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12487] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu May 19 08:05:25.513275 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14456] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 19 08:05:25.513343 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14456] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu May 19 08:26:11.093404 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14456] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu May 19 08:26:12.166600 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20497] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 19 08:26:12.166640 2016] [core:notice] [pid 20497] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: is it an old php page ... check the code and see if its using `<?` instead of `<?php` .. if it is using the short version then you will need to change it everywhere it shows up in the page.

Comment: I am using <?php but still not working

Comment: have you tried the phpinfo page `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` create a page called phpinfo.php and put in that line .. then try to go to that and tell me what error if any you receive

Comment: It is showing a Blank page..... Total Blank.... its look like PHP is not working... no error not any thing

Comment: have you checked apache's error log to see if it tells you anything? usually its located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: [Thu May 19 08:26:12.166640 2016] [core:notice] [pid 20497] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: you may want to add it to your question... there had to be more that only one line

Comment: looks like you have a conflict somewhere there .. its loading PHP 5.5.9 but you have 7.0 .. you may have to look at your apache2 files and change any references from /etc/php5 to /etc/php/7.0

Comment: ok.... did you know how to remove php5 from my machine?

Comment: sorry im only going by what I saw .. Not sure how to remove or change it .. I have both showing on mine and I too have my whole website non-functioning .. .but for me at least the phpinfo page works. make sure that the permissions are right on the files .. make sure that they are www-data:www-data for user:group other than that... not really sure where to go from here . i;m sure someone will be able to help

Comment: I have 777 permissions on that page

Comment: sorry then .. that's as far as I can take it .. as I said . I myself have an ongoing question about my site and php not functioning properly but at least I can get php to somewhat work .. I run zoneminder and owncloud which run php and they work but my site doesn't :( .. so sorry .. I;m out of ideas for you :(

Comment: But you are really helpful for me... I remove all Php and apache 2 from my machine.... now going to install php 7 let see whats happend

Comment: Hi There! could you please [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/774492/edit) your question and post the output for `php -v` & `whereis php`. Just to make it more clearer, add the output for `type -a php` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install `libapache2-mod-php7.0` in addition to `libapache2-mod-php5` it will not enable itself (you should see this in {apt,dpkg}.log), so you need to disable `php5` module and enable `php7.0` module:

```
a2dismod php5
a2enmod php7.0
apache2ctl restart
```

P.S.: You should read what the packages tells you at the installation time.  Running apt-get with `-y` is a quite sure way how to miss important stuff.